# Issue with display: flex & column-count: 2

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I am trying to create two columns that are a certain width. Both columns have an image and text below the image. I have managed this with:

```
.quick-links img {
    height: 7.5em;
    width: 7.5em;
    border-radius: 10em;
    margin: 0 15em;
}

.quick-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

However, whenever the website shrinks down past about a width of 1200px something weird begins to happen:

https://gyazo.com/5f01aa7248873d999dd6552e089b1c2f

[image]

This is extremely annoying because what I thought would be something quite simple to make, has turned out to be a nightmare!

I have also tried:

```
.quick-links img {
    height: 7.5em;
    width: 7.5em;
    border-radius: 10em;
    margin: 0 15em;
}

.quick-links {
    column-count: 2;
    display; inline-block;
}
```

However, this issue then occurs:

[image]

I am very stumped and would love for someone to help me.

For reference, here is the HTML:

```
<section class="quicklinks">
        <h1>Quicklinks</h1>
        <div class="quick-links">
            <!-- Client Reviews -->
            <figure class="reviews">
                <img src="images/RatingsTick.png" alt="Ratings Tick Image">
                <figcaption class="port-desc">
                    <p><strong>Reviews</strong></p>
                    <p>-Filler Text-</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>

            <!-- Portfolio -->
            <figure class="portfolio">
                <img src="images/Portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio Image">
                <figcaption class="port-desc">
                    <p><strong>Previous Work</strong></p>
                    <p>-Filler Text-</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>

</section>
```

Comment: what is the behavior you are expecting when window shrinks ? text to be hidden or boxes to stack ?

Comment: Yes I want to get the two boxes to stack when the windows shrinks. If I am correct wouldn't I use a media query that says min-width: 25em, display: inline

Comment: so the min-width to your flex children is the hint if you allow the flex parent to wrap :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow flex children to wrap you need to set `flex-wrap:wrap;`.

You may also set a `min-width` to create a break point almost alike mediaquerie would.

```css
.quick-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

figure {
  min-width:25em;/* or whatever value suits your needs */
  border: solid;/* see me */
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="quicklinks">
  <h1>Quicklinks</h1>
  <div class="quick-links">
    <!-- Client Reviews -->
    <figure class="reviews">
      <img src="images/RatingsTick.png" alt="Ratings Tick Image">
      <figcaption class="port-desc">
        <p><strong>Reviews</strong></p>
        <p>-Filler Text-</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <figure class="portfolio">
      <img src="images/Portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio Image">
      <figcaption class="port-desc">
        <p><strong>Previous Work</strong></p>
        <p>-Filler Text-</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

</section>
```

About `column-count`, it can seem usefull but this is a CSS rule that unfortunately remained in the css draft, flex seems much more efficient here.

Comment: EDIT:
I feel like I need to explain that better. At a large screen size currently, the boxes are not next to each other and one is above the other. I thought changing min-width would stop this but it doesn't. I want both boxes to wrap at a certain screen size and I want the p elements to also wrap at a certain screen size.

Comment: I have made an image on Photoshop to portray what I want to happen when at a larger screen size (Anything bigger than around 1100px width). Also currently, at a large screen size the boxes aren't the same width, how would I make sure they're always the same, even if that means the texts wraps more often?

https://i.gyazo.com/2a1779699277164e650a4f72ff782259.png

Comment: @JShepherd is this morelike what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OEPMvJ

Comment: Exactly that, but I have managed to do this now through my own accord. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margin from the img elements and it will center properly.

Use `.quick-links figure { min-width: 500px;}` to set a minimum width on the text.

Comment: But I want the img elements to be separated by a certain amount. How would I achieve the above and this?

Comment: Plus I am trying to set a 500px width on the text. How would I achieve this since I am using display: flex so column-width is void

Comment: Use  .quick-links figure { min-width: 500px;} to set a minimum width on the text.